# Nodejs Net TCP client data event triggered without any write action in server side

Tags: node.js

I was using net module to build a simple server/client example.  The client side just send a simple message after connection is built, and server side didn't do anything but just print some log, but after that I found the data event in client side got triggered, and the data received is the data it send to the server (but server didn't write anything to client).

Client.js:

```
var net = require('net');

  var port = 3540;
  var hostName = "127.0.0.1";

  var client = new net.Socket();
  client.connect(port, hostName, function() {
     console.log("Connected to the remote host: " + hostName + ":" + port);
     client.write("hello,world");
     client.end();
  });
  var bytesReceived = 0;
  client.on('data', function(data) {
    bytesReceived += data.length;
    console.log('Received bytes: ' + data.length + ', total bytes received: ' + bytesReceived);
    console.log(data.toString())
    })

  client.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    client.destroy();
  });

  client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Closed connection');
  })
```

server.js:

```
var net = require('net');
    port = 3540;

var log = function(who, what) {
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log('[%s on %s]', who, what, args);
  };
};
var count = 0
var echo = function (socket) {
  socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('recevied a FIN packet');
    socket.end();
  });
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(count + ': received bytes: ' + data.length);
    count++;
  });
  socket.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    socket.destroy();
  });
  socket.on('close', function() {
    console.log('connection has been closed!');
  });
  socket.pipe(socket);
}


var server = net.createServer(echo);
server.listen(port); // port or unix socket, cannot listen on both with one server

server.on('listening', function() {
  var ad = server.address();
  if (typeof ad === 'string') {
    console.log('[server on listening] %s', ad);
  } else {
    console.log('[server on listening] %s:%s using %s', ad.address, ad.port, ad.family);
  }
});

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  server.getConnections(function(err, count) {
    console.log('%d open connections!', count);
  });
});

server.on('close', function() { console.log('[server on close]'); });
server.on('err', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  server.close(function() { console.log("shutting down the server!"); });
});
```

After that the client print out:

```
Connected to the remote host: 127.0.0.1:3540
Received bytes: 11, total bytes received: 11
hello,world
Closed connection
```

Answer (score 1):

> but server didn't write anything to client

It does:

```
socket.pipe(socket)
```

This will echo the data received *from* the client (represented by `socket`) back *to* the client.